# C read access violation - Pointers

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm new to C and I'm getting a little tangled up with the Visual Studio Code.

I did not understand what that meant.

When I run the code in another compiler it does run.

```
        void swap(int* x, int *y);
        int exe1(int* num1Ptr, int* num2Ptr, int* num3Ptr);
    
        int main()
        {
            int a = 123, b = 456 , c =4;
            int* pa, * pb ,*pc;
            pa = &a;
            pb = &b;
            pc = &c; 
    
            printf("pa = %d , pb = %d, pc = %d\n", *pa, *pb, *pc);
            exe1(pa, pb, pc);
            printf("pa = %d , pb = %d, pc = %d\n", *pa, *pb, *pc);

            return 0;
        }
    
    
        void swap(int* x, int* y) {
            int temp = *x; 
            *x = *y;
            *y = *x; 
        }
    
    
        int exe1(int* num1Ptr, int* num2Ptr, int* num3Ptr) {
            if (*num2Ptr > *num1Ptr) {
                swap(*num1Ptr, *num2Ptr);
            }
            if (*num3Ptr > *num2Ptr) {
                swap(*num3Ptr, *num2Ptr);
            }
            if (*num3Ptr > *num1Ptr) {
                swap(*num3Ptr, *num1Ptr);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Your calls to swap should be passing num1Ptr not *num1Ptr etc. You compiler should have given you a warning about this.

Comment: Your swap function never uses `temp`, very suspicious.

Comment: passing argument 1 of 'swap' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: `swap(*num1Ptr, *num2Ptr);` --> `swap(num1Ptr, num2Ptr);`

Comment: `*y = *x;` --> `*y = tmp;`

Answer (score 2):

```
void swap(int* x, int* y) {
    int temp = *x; 
    *x = *y;
    *y = *x;  // this should be *y = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*"read access violation"* occurs when we try to access a memory address which we don't have access to. In this case it is because of `swap(*num1Ptr, *num2Ptr);`

This function expects a pointer (relating to memory address) and should be called as `swap(num1Ptr, num2Ptr);`

`*num1Ptr` dereferences the pointer, it is now an integer value, not a pointer to a valid address. For example `*num1Ptr` can be `123` in the above code. Whatever sits at memory address `123` is probably used by system and we don't have read/write access to it. Debugger throws access violation.

The compiler should also print warnings.

The swap function needs a fix `*y = temp;` as noted earlier.

---

Unrelated to your question, `exe1` compares values in this order

```
p1 & p2 
p2 & p3 
p1 & p3
```

If this were intended as a sort function for example, the third condition can negate the first condition. You may want to change the order of comparison as shown below:

```
void swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void exe1(int* p1, int* p2, int* p3)
{
    if (*p1 < *p2) swap(p1, p2);
    if (*p1 < *p3) swap(p1, p3);
    if (*p2 < *p3) swap(p2, p3);
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    a = 123, b = 456, c = 4;
    exe1(&a, &b, &c); printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
    a = 123, b = 456, c = 4000;
    exe1(&a, &b, &c); printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `swap` routine expects two pointers to `int` and you pass two `int`s to it.  Remove superfluous asterisks from the calls:

```
swap(*num1Ptr, *num2Ptr);
```

should read

```
swap(num1Ptr, num2Ptr);
```

Plus the mistake inside `swap()` which Kaitou points out in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70224807/733637).